# Iphone menu icon duplicates when moving from horizontal to vertical view

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am writing a responsive website and while debugging with my iphone5 (and also iphone 7) I noticed something strange.
I have a menu strip with an "hamburger" icon in it (consists of 3 spans).
When moving to horizontal view and than to vertical view- a part of the screen get stuck, so the hamburger icon is now presented on both sides of the screen and also some of the right part is missing (it shows white gap on the right edge)
it looks like the device got lost when moving from one view to another.

Here is my header **html code** which holds the navbar:

```
<header>
    <div>
        <h1 class="title">ניווט ראשי</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="header-menu" >
        <div class="nav-button" onclick="" >
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper" >

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="btnGoBack" runat ="server" href="#">חזור</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:window.location.reload()">רענן</a>
                    </li>
                     <li><a href="Logout.aspx">התנתק</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and here is the **CSS**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px)
{

.logo{
        margin: 42px 0 58px;
}
.logo img{
    width: 105px;
}
.main>h1{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.logo-form{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 59px auto 50px;
}
.form-line{
    height: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form-line-grid{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form-line .icon{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.form-line .form-input{
    height: 96%;
}
.form-line .form-input input{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
.logo-form button{
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.inner header{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.inner header .title{
    font-size: 2em;
}
.nav-button{
    height: 44px;
    width: 51px;
    bottom: 16px;
}
.nav-button span{
    height: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.sections{
    margin-top: 32px;
}
.sections>div{
    width: 85px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
.section{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.sections .section-icon{
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
}
.sections .section-icon span{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.sections h3{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.icon-list-custom{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 33px;
}
.icon-cart{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png') no-repeat -37px 0;
    width: 31px;
    height: 33px;
}
.icon-shop{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png')no-repeat -71px 0;
    width: 36px;
    height: 32px;
}
.icon-calendar-custom{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png')no-repeat -110px 0;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}
.icon-search{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png') no-repeat -147px -4px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
.icon-reload-custom{
    background: url('../img/sprites-mob.png')no-repeat -174px 0;
    width: 39px;
    height: 34px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-list-custom,
.sections>div:hover .icon-list-custom{
    background-position: 0 -34px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-cart,
.sections>div:hover .icon-cart{
    background-position: -37px -34px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-shop,
.sections>div:hover .icon-shop{
    background-position: -71px -35px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-calendar-custom,
.sections>div:hover .icon-calendar-custom{
    background-position: -110px -34px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-search,
.sections>div:hover .icon-search{
    background-position: -147px -35px;
}
.sections>div.active .icon-reload-custom,
.sections>div:hover .icon-reload-custom{
    background-position: -174px -36px;
}
.charts h2{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.sections .count{
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
nav a{
    font-size: 25px;
}

}
```

Comment: I also noticed that this is happening only when using the "add to home screen feature". so if viewing in "normal" safari browser it does not happen, but when viewing from home screen it does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`
and I removed the `initial-scale=1` and it worked